# The restriction of a covering map on the connected component of its definition domain

Tags: general-topology, covering-spaces

Suppose $p:Y\to X$ is a covering map, $X,Y$ are manifolds and $X$ is connected. If $Z$ is a connected component of $Y$, I wonder if the restriction of $p$ on $Z$ is also a covering map? If not, what conditions should be added to guarantee the restriction is a covering map? (expect that $Y$ is compact.)

What I do: I know only need to show $p(Z)=X$. $p$ is a local homeomorphism and thus an open map. $Z$ is an open set since $Y$ is locally connected, and of course a closed set, so $p(Z)$ is an open set. Then I want to show $p(Z)$ is also closed, thus $p(Z)$ is open and closed in a connected space $X$, so $p(Z)=X$. But I cannot show $p(Z)$ is closed, perhaps I try a wrong way.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

I'll use the definition of covering map as it appears in Hatcher's [Algebraic Topology](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATpage.html):  A continuous map $p:Y\to X$ is called a covering map, if for every $x\in X$ there is an open neighborhood $U$ around $x$ whose preimage is a (possibly empty) disjoint union of open sets, each of which is mapped homeomorphically onto $U$ via $p$. Note that this definition does not require a covering map to be surjective.

Still, if the codomain is connected, the map must be surjective by the following argument:

Assume $x\notin p(Y)$. Then its preimage $p^{-1}(x)$ is empty. There is an open $U$ containing $x$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ equals $\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha\approx U$ and all $U_\alpha$ are open. But since $x$ is not in the image of $p$, the disjoint union must be the empty union. This means that $U$ does not intersect $p(Y)$, so $p(Y)$ is closed.
On the other hand, $p$ is an open map. If $V\subset Y$ is an open set containing $y$ and $U$ is the evenly covered neighborhood of $p(y)$, then $y$ is contained in some $U_\alpha$. Since $V\cap U_\alpha$ is open, $p(V\cap U_\alpha)$ is an open subset of $U$, thus an open set in $X$ which is contained in $p(V)$, so $p(V)$ is open.
If $X$ is connected, then $p(Y)$ must be all of $X$, being a clopen subset of a connected space.

To prove that the restriction of the $p$ in your problem to the connected component $Z$ is also a covering map, take an $x\in X$ and an open neighborhood $U$ such that $p^{-1}(U)$ equals $\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I}U_\alpha$ where $U_\alpha\stackrel p\approx U$ and all $U_\alpha$ are open. Since $X$ is locally connected, there is an open connected $V$ such that $x\in V\subset U$. Its preimage is $\bigsqcup_{\alpha\in I}V_\alpha$ where $V_\alpha$  is simply the preimage of $V$ in the particular $U_\alpha$. Each $V_\alpha$ is connected, so it is either entirely in $Z$ or it is disjoint to $Z$. If you delete all the $V_\alpha$'s which are not in $Z$ from the union, you obtain the preimage of $V$ under the restriction of $p$. This means that this restricted $p$ still is a covering map.

Comment: According to your definition of covering map,if p:Y-> X a surjetive covering map,X is a subset Z,then p:Y-> Z is also a covering map,am I right?

Comment: That is the definition Allen Hatcher uses in his book. If you replace $X$ by a larger space $Z$, then $p:Y\to Z$ it is a covering map if and only if $p(Y)$ is open and closed. Otherwise the defining property would not be satisfies.

Comment: Thank you for your reply,but if I want to solve my problem,I have to verify p:Z->X is a covering map according to Allen Hatcher,I know p:Z->p(Z) is a covering according to him,as you say,I finally have to verify p(Z) is clopen,Which is the problem that I cannot solve(Sorry,all the notations are the same as that in the post)

Comment: @huabin_li. I completed my answer.

Comment: yeah,your answer does help me,but vote up requires 15 reputation and I have only 13

Comment: @huabin_li:  Ah, that's funny, I thought you could always vote up for answers to your own question, as you also can comment on answers to your own question. Does not make sense in my opinion. I think they should change that. Thanks for clarifying this, I really had no idea.